# Reordering Groups with forecast, but rearrange the position of one single group

Tags: r

I have a Boxplot with over twenty groups  (and it  still may change), that i reordered using `fct_reorder`; there is one group (Control Group) that i would like to put in a certain spot (either first or last), to divide it from the mass.

Is there an easy way to do this, without using a manual defined order (as there might be that we add additional groups/data, and we have to change all again)?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
data_CK <- CKRF %>% 
  select(CK, Group) %>% 
  mutate(Group = factor(Group, order = TRUE, labels = c("Neurologische Erkrankungen", "Arterielle Thromboembolie", "Kardiologische Erkrankungen", "Atemwegserkrankungen", 
                                                        "Pleuraerguss", "Nephropathien", "Probleme der Ableitende Harnwege", "Gastro-Intestinal Erkrankungen", "Leber/Pankreas", 
                                                        "Endokrinologische Erkrankugen", "Neoplasie", "Anämie", "Ophtalmologische Erkrankungen", "Dermatologische Erkrankungen", 
                                                        "Gynäkologische Erkrankungen", "Bewegapparat Probleme", "Anorexie", "Kontrollgruppe",
                                                        "Trauma", "Fieber Unbekannter Ursache")))



ggplot(data_CK, aes(x = fct_reorder(Group,CK), y = CK)) +  
         geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0.2) +
  #coord_trans(y = 'log10') +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", breaks = c(350,1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 1000000)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  #geom_point(size = 0.5) + 
  labs(y = 'CK (IU/L)', x = 'Erkrankungen') + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.x = element_text(angle =  90, hjust = 1))
```

[image: Generated Boxplot, whit clear issue: How to relocate only one group]

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the order of your factor `levels`. Use `relevel` (convenient for using within formulas) or `factor(., levels=)`. *Example (using base plots):*

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 3))

with(iris, boxplot(Petal.Length ~ Species))  ## original order

with(iris, boxplot(Petal.Length ~ relevel(Species, ref="virginica")))  ## virginica first (re)level

## custom order levels (set "virginica" so that it appears last)
iris2 <- transform(iris, 
                   Species=factor(iris$Species, 
                                  levels=c("versicolor", "setosa", "virginica")))
with(iris2, boxplot(Petal.Length ~ Species))

par(op)
```

[image]

*Note:* Make sure to not confuse `levels` with `labels`; in your case they should match.

Comment: But this means  i should define this before using the ggplot, and then "don't touch" the order in the ggplot function, correct?

Comment: Yeah, define the labels before using `ggplot`; `"Kontrollgruppe"` simply should be the last element of the `levels` of your `data_CK$Group`. You could try `levels(data_CK$Group) <- c("Neurologische Erkrankungen", ..., "Kontrollgruppe")`, where in `...` fill in all your other levels; after the `mutate` code, before the `ggplot` code.

Comment: Yeah but that is exactly my point, I could do the same thing with dplyr and mutate the order, and rewrite every single group in the position I want. I would like to know if there was an automatic way to tell him "yeah follow that order", and then to say "ok now put this last"

Comment: Well that should be covered by the solution in the middle. Does replacing `fct_reorder(Group, CK)` with `relevel(Group, ref="Kontrollgruppe")` give you what you want?